# Ruby on rails 3: link_to :remote => true treats "remote" as a URL parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to know what the link_to syntax is supposed to be for making ajax requests (or other ideas on what might be going wrong here).  Currently I have

```
<%= form_tag "save_sets", :remote => true, :name => "set_form" do %>
```

in a file and it works perfectly.  However, in the very same file, all of

```
<%= link_to assignment.name, :action => :view_student_problem_set, :remote => true %>
<%= link_to assignment.name, :remote => true, :action => :view_student_problem_set %>
<%= link_to assignment.name, {:action => :view_student_problem_set, :remote => true} %>
<%= link_to assignment.name, {:remote => true, :action => :view_student_problem_set} %>
<%= link_to assignment.name, {:remote => true}, {:action => :view_student_problem_set} 
<%= link_to assignment.name, {:remote => true}, :action => :view_student_problem_set %>
```

just produce links with "?remote=true" instead of data-remote="true", and

```
<%= link_to assignment.name, :remote => true, {:action => :view_student_problem_set} %>
```

is apparently a syntax error.

Most of the combinations I have tried are from tutorials, forum posts, and documentation.  I didn't think that collections of symbols had to be in a particular order, but I was just being thorough.  In any event, my googling skills have met their match.

The relevant jquery code, controller code, and whatnot is all identical between the form_tag and the link_to tags.

Thanks and all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<%= link_to assignment.name, {:action => :view_student_problem_set}, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks, that works.  As a follow-up question, 'any suggestions on where to go to find out stuff like that?  As far as I can tell, this page (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) just states it's possible but doesn't say how to actually do it...